# Update Conda .yml File Automatically

Tags: python, yaml, conda, environment

I was wondering if there is a way to set conda to update a specific .yml file whenever a new package is installed in a specific environment.

I want to achieve a similar behavior to npm and the package.json file.

I know this can be achieved by creating a bash script and an alias for the conda command but I am more interested to know if there is a Conda native method for achieving this.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not. You can submit an issue over on their GitHub repository if you'd like to discuss adding this with the developers.

Comment: Wow, how is this not an option or even the default? `yarn` and `npm` do this so well. [I filed an issue with `conda`](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9118).